# Jamaica Auto Rental Insurance

Tags: car-rentals, automobiles, insurance, jamaica

I made a reservation through Expedia for thrifty.com auto rentals in MBJ (Montego Bay, Jamaica airport). I bought rental car insurance from Expedia and read the insurer's fine print.  There was a point about not covering damages where prohibited by law.  I called the insurer and they could not / would not advise if the policy was valid in JA.

If I make the reservation again through Thrifty and buy the policy through Thrifty, can I be certain that if the car is damaged / stolen, I will be covered?

Also, what are the common insurance pitfalls applicable for me?

Comment: I don't see why the clause you state would be a problem. "not covering damages where prohibited by law" means things like you cannot insure against criminal fines for example.

Comment: Different trips

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would like to take the chance to warn you off of this particular provider. As per [this person's review](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g147309-i69-k9584748-Beware_of_Thrifty_Car_Rental_at_Mobay_Airport-Jamaica.html),

> The name on the rental agreement [on the car picked up at Thrifty at the MBJ airport] is with a company called Tropical Tours Car Rental, not Thrifty.

Also, as per [this site's](http://rentalcarreviews.com/jamaica/thrifty-car-rental-montego-bay-sangster-international-airport-mbj-jamaica) numerous reviews, the Thrifty (whether or not it is actually Thrifty) company is incredibly misleading in that particular area and the insurance in particular is detestable.

However, as per your actual question, "not covering damages where prohibited by law" means that they will not insure you if you do something criminal or otherwise illegal, or that the law prohibits them from doing so. This would most definetely be the case no matter what country you have rented a car in and would depend on Jamaican law. Bottom line: **if you don't do anything illegal, this doesn't apply to you.**

That particular part of the fine print doesn't relate to covering losses because of theft, so I'd read the rest of it to make sure. In any case, since Thrifty in MBJ isn't reputable, I'd be careful.